# enableFields in Fluid powered TYPO3 Section -> Object

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux, fedext

I'm just starting to use Fluid powered TYPO3 now (with the great extensions from Claus Due [flux, fluidpages, fluidcontent, vhs, etc.])

What I want to do is:

- Using a Flexform Object inside a Section to add multiple Content
- Use something similar toenableFields

My Flexform configuration in the Content Template File (in folder EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Templates/Content) looks something like this

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:flexform wizardTab="Speciality" id="heroWidget">
        <flux:flexform.section name="elements">
            <flux:flexform.object name="heroteaser">
                <flux:flexform.field.text name="title" />
                <flux:flexform.field.input name="description" />
            </flux:flexform.object>
        </flux:flexform.section>
    </flux:flexform>
</f:section>
```

My question now: **Is it possible to add in the configuration something like the enableField mechanism?** I want to have fields like start, stop, hidden, group access as you know from regular tt_content element in the `[Access]` Sheet.

Of course it is possible to add the field by myself and the add some confitions in the `"Main"` section, but that would be tearse and I guess it would not serve the purpose as I suppose there will be cache issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahoi there!

As you are using fluidcontent, you have the `{record}` variable available. This variable contains all the stored information of the parent record.

For fiddeling around, what's available, do a `{record -> f:debug()}` in your template and have a look at the available fields. Your desired values should also be present.

Be aware that:

- You can only use the parent records access fields
- OR: create the fields yourself
- OR: Use a crazy displayCond to archieve what you're looking for

Cheers,
Cedric

Comment: You mean `{record -> f:debug()}`?

Comment: But I don't want to have the partners embraced fields, but independent enable fields control for every section object for itself.

Comment: Its like what I said. You have to craft those fields yourself if the parent records dont suffice. If you reference foreign entities, those might bring their own fields. In Flux you are basically crafting your own fields-so you have to care about that yourself.